# Can segmentation faults happen due to scanf statements

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Written a program to find the multiplication of two polynomials using linked list. Checked for all the possible segementation faults finding no errors (checked the multiplication function).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int co;
    int po;
    struct node *add;
};
typedef struct node *NODE;
NODE addterms(NODE,int ,int);
NODE insert(NODE start,int co,int po)
{
    NODE temp;
    NODE cur;
    temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->co=co;
    temp->po=po;
    temp->add=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    cur=start;
    while(cur->add!=NULL)
    {
        cur=cur->add;
    }
    cur->add=temp;
    return start;
}
void display(NODE start)
{
    NODE cur;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL");
    }
    else
    {
         cur=start;
        while(cur->add!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d X^%d +",cur->co,cur->po);
            cur=cur->add;
        }
        printf("%d X^%d",cur->co,cur->po);
    }
}
NODE multiply(NODE poly1,NODE poly2)
{
    NODE res=NULL;NODE first=NULL,second=NULL;
    for( first=poly1;first!=NULL;first=first->add)
    {
        for(second=poly2;second!=NULL;second=second->add)
        {
            res = addterms(res,(first->co*second->co),(first->po+second->po));  
        }
    }
    return res;
}
NODE addterms(NODE res,int co, int po)
{
    NODE temp,cur;
    temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->co=co;
    temp->po=po;
    temp->add=NULL;
    if(res==NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cur=res;int flag=0;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            if(cur->po==po)
            {
                cur->co=cur->co+co;
                flag=1;
            }       
            cur=cur->add;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            cur=res;
            while(cur!=NULL)
            {
                cur=cur->add;
            }
            cur->add=temp;
        }
        return res;
    }
    
}
int main()
{
    NODE poly1=NULL,poly2=NULL;
    NODE res; int n,n1;int co,co1,po1,po;
    printf("Enter the number of polynomial terms");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the co and po of %d term ",i);
        scanf("%d%d",&co,&po);
        poly1=insert(poly1,co,po);
        
    }
    display(poly1);
    printf("Enter the number of second polynomial terms");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    for(int i=1;i<=n1;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the poly2 of co and po of %d term ",i);
        scanf("%d%d",&co1,&po1);
        printf ("Insert");
        poly2=insert(poly2,co1,po1);    
    }
    display(poly2);
    printf("MULTIPLICATION");
    res=multiply(poly1,poly2);
    display(res);
    return 0;
}
```

THE OUTPUT IS THIS:

```
Enter the number of polynomial terms
2
Enter the co and po of 1 term 
2 2
Enter the co and po of 2 term 
2 4
2 X^2 +2 X^4Enter the number of second polynomial terms2
Enter the poly2 of co and po of 1 term 2 1
InsertEnter the poly2 of co and po of 2 term 2 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Soo... The insertion does not happenn for the last variable ONLY! Even if the number of terms are n ..the care dumps at n-1.

```
for(int i=1;i<=n1;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the poly2 of co and po of %d term ",i);
        scanf("%d%d",&co1,&po1);
        printf ("Insert");
        poly2=insert(poly2,co1,po1);    
    }
```

I belive there is a  mistake at this part only.Can it be the scanf statments?

Comment: In C, memory allocation is largely your responsibility.  So you always have to be careful of your pointers, to make sure they point to validly-allocated memory. So: (1) functions that return new pointers, like your `insert()` and `addterms()`, are problematic and deserve special care, and (b) typedefs that hide pointers, like your `NODE`, are arguably a bad idea, since they can cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: `scanf` was actually a popular reason for segfaults until compilers were able to warn about missing or wrongly typed arguments (no address operator).

Comment: The question shouldn't be "Can scanf cause segmentation faults?" so much as "how can I use scanf without causing a segmentation fault?"  It is a notoriously terrible tool that has led to a *lot* of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Adding printfs to trace, like the printf("MULTIPLICATION"); need a newline in order to flush; otherwise when your program faults, it exits without flushing its buffers to stdout.

In this sequence, around line 86:

```
            cur=res;
            while(cur!=NULL)
            {
                cur=cur->add;
            }
            cur->add=temp;
```

When you assign to cur->add, it is guaranteed that cur == NULL, do to the condition of the while loop.   That is causing the SIGSEGV.
Even if you don't like debuggers, running it in a debugger shows the precise location of the fault.

Comment: thanks you soo much which debugger do you recommend?

Comment: On this I used lldb, because I was on a mac.   On linux, gdb.   On windows, I've only ever used cygwin, so gdb again.   Any should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function `addterms` can produce a memory leak because a node was allocated in the beginning of the function

```
temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

but if `flag` was set to `1` then the node is not added to the list

```
    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
        if(cur->po==po)
        {
            cur->co=cur->co+co;
            flag=1;
        }       
        cur=cur->add;
    }
```

You are trying to add a node to the list only when `flag` is equal to `0`.

And moreover when `flag` is equal to `0` you are using a null pointer to access memory

```
    if(flag==0)
    {
        cur=res;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            cur=cur->add;
        }
        cur->add=temp;
    }
```

because after the while loop the pointer `cur` is equal to `NULL` due to the condition of the while loop.

You need to rewrite the while loop the same way as such a loop is written in the function `insert`

```
while(cur->add!=NULL)
{
    cur=cur->add;
}
cur->add=temp;
```